# Uninstalling command-line software on OS X

Tags: macos, command-line, uninstall

I have past experience installing software via the command line and working from the command line, but it's been a while and I am not as savvy as I once was. One of the command line software packages I installed I wish to remove. It was installed using make and configure commands provided through XCode. I am guessing that there is a list of commands to run should one wish to uninstall the package(s) but I am unfamiliar with them. I would prefer uninstalling rather than simply deleting since there may be dependencies specific to this app that I will also not need.

Basically, I'd like a command (or set of commands) for reversing an install script as the provided documentation for the software does not include instructions for removing it.

BTW, this is NOT a MacPorts install ... that interface is very straightforward and well documented.

Answer (score 2):

> Basically, I'd like a command (or set of commands) for reversing an install script as the provided documentation for the software does not include instructions for removing it.

There is no such thing as a general uninstall script for software in OS X. Especially one that would revert changes made by a custom installation script.

Your only chance is if the developer/vendor of the software provided an uninstallation script. If they did not, you can only try to reengineer the installation process and revert the changes manually.

---

Notice that although the package managers like Homebrew and MacPorts provide a very easy interface for the user, under the hood they are a set of elaborate scripts customised individually for each package.

[Here](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/tree/master/Formula) you can see Homebrew formulas (installation/uninstallation scripts) for currently 3,594 (three thousand five hundred ninety four) separate packages, each of which was manually written by someone.